# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Geographic Information Systems' [third moderator election](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Aaron] [image: iant]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5973084905406464/0).

Comment: Congrats Aaron and PolyGeo

Comment: Thanks to everyone who participated in the election and all of the fellow nominees.  I look forward to helping maintain the quality of the best GIS QA site on the web.

Comment: Thanks to those who stood, asked questions of the candidates and voted, and congratulations to Aaron who I am looking forward to "meeting" along with the other moderators soon.

Comment: I for one welcome our new overlords!

Comment: Congratulations, Aaron and Polygeo.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks

Comment: Congrats Aaron and PolyGeo

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks to all the moderators for their time, it is an invaluable site.

Comment: Congratulations PolyGeo and Aaron..

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Aaron and PolyGeo, congratulations and welcome to the moderator team!

Thank you for picking up this role, even as I leave the fold. Moderating can be work, annoying at times, but worth the effort. Whenever you find yourself in doubt, step back and survey the extent and value of the growing body of great questions and answers found here, and enjoy the part you're playing in bringing that to fruition.

Comment: Thanks Matt - my other mod experience is on a relatively quiet Beta site so I am looking forward to the challenge of resolving a larger variety of scenarios - your efforts as mod and contributor here are greatly appreciated.